# App running on server, writing XML files - does it need to be a console app?

Tags: delphi, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I've coded an application that generates XML files for use with a mobile phone app using Delphi 7. The application was developed using forms etc. It exits when done. Can this be run once a day as-is, or do I have to make it a console application or add code to allow it be run by the server? The scheduled execution is done by the host.

The application is about 60% done.

It's basically just a heads-up question, so that I know about any snafus beforehand.

Does someone with experience have some helpful tips?

I'm also interested to know if writing files in a server environment (to folders to which I have write access) needs special handling somehow.

Edit: finished it (a while ago) and it writes files accessible via http without any problems. (Well, after configuring IE8 to not require human intervention for every pageload (Trusted Sites/Enhanced Security etc...))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run your App from Task Scheduler and you'll be fine.

Comment: In other words, It does not need to be a console app (just to answer the question) :D

Comment: It wouldn't have to be a console app, but in this situation a GUI makes no sense, and your app can be hung, waiting for input.  Ideally, you'd have a console app that logs to a text file. If it runs successfully, you have the BOJ/EOJ with timestamps. If it blows up or has a handled exception, that shows in the log.  You really don't want to have to remdesk into the server to see what's going on.

Comment: @Chris T: It makes sense and is a desirable thing, partly for the visual output which is better than (more easily human-readable) and less work than adding many log statements, and partly because (for the same reasons) it can be modified more easily. Also, adapting it to a console app is extra work so I doubt my boss would accept unnecessary hours to make it less useful ;) There will of course be a log, but with only the essentials.

Comment: I should add that it now has a nice log with timestamps and handles errors by exiting gracefully. No files are left open including the log file, and if it lacks the 'Finished on xx:yy:zz' the error can be detected without human intervention.

Answer (score 2):

normally your gui (forms stuff) is just an overlay to existing objects. If this abstraction is implemented correctly you should be able to write a small console application, that does nothing but execute your stuff (create main worker object and run the task)...

In general its not a good idea to launch forms applications on a server.. but if it doesn't require interaction (clicking on things) it should work...

Writing files on a server may be a little bit trickier than on a local machine... except your software runs on the server.. Normally you would access all files with a complete URI like file:///c:/whatever/wherever/

All in all its not a big hazle :)

Comment: `Normally you would access all files with a complete URI like file:///c:/whatever/wherever/`: Why? And why is it not a good idea to launch forms application on a server?

Comment: The URI defines an absolute path to a file and is somewhat safer to use. There is just less place for errors.

Why should one launch an application with a GUI on a server? The users don't see the forms and the admin is normally connected via console.. so no forms either :)

Comment: I fail to see how the full path name is safer. Here's a (bad) full path name: `ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'FileInMyFolder.bin'`. The admin doesn't necessary connect to the Windows server using a "console". I have no idea how "Pro" admins handling many machines do it, but I'm using Remote Desktop to administer my servers and I'm pretty sure Microsoft expects me to do so since they're providing *grate* administrative GUI's.

Comment: Your example is a bad uri because of the missing check wheter ParamStr(0) is set up correctly. The URI itself will point to an existing file or not. There is no guessing :)

And I really didn't want to start a "pro"/"noob" administrator discussion. If the way you are doing it works for you, its perfect! But I'm a client side developer.. so from my perspective, every form rendered on the server means wasted ressources, that could be used to answer client requests (one users needs <-> many clients needs) :)

And I don't like Microsoft.. But thats another story :D

Comment: @Jonas, `ParamStr(0)` is always set up correctly and it's the full path name to the currently running exe. What I assume you're trying to say is that it's preferable not to use RELATIVE paths: but that's just as wrong, because the application may safely change the active directory to it's working directory and then use relative paths without issues. I think the `normally you would access all files with a complete URI` is your own opinion, and I think it's wrong. If you have any reference to that, please provide a link, I'd like to read about it. But don't give me obscure forum links.

Comment: @Jonas, about the "it is not a good idea to launch forms application on a server", my problem's that the statement is much too broad. First of all the penalty for using Forms (ie: windows) is not as grate as you'd think it is. Secondly GUI application have a place on servers. Given a choice between using `adduser` with all it's options on Linux and using the `Add a New User Account` on my SBS Server, I'd use the GUI Wizard every time.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund
You're right with ParamStr(0). It's just my personall experience from the last years of developement that its far more reliable to use aboslute paths. Especially when you have other devs using your code. People tend to be lazy and in addition to that, you'll just have to check one thing (is the file present) and you know if its ok or not.. In your described case you'll have to check if you've set your base path correctly. This CAN obviously be done in a safe way, but my experience tells me, that the most stupid mistake is def. gonna happen :) But of course thats not the only way!

Comment: And about the gui on server stuff..
For adding users etc. you're propably right (Im not that experienced in managing servers and happy to learn new stuff about that), but what he was describing in his question seems to be something that could and should be done by a cronjob. And there's deffinetly no point in launching gui applications, which propably get stuck because of missing clicks on buttons, just to do the job of a cronjob :)

Comment: @Jonas, you're not truly using "absolute paths" in your application unless you're using *hard coded paths*, and using hard coded paths is a sin. For Desktop applications you're supposed to write to the user's AppData folder, and in there you're probably going to create your own sub folder. For Servers, at a minimum, you need to allow the user to install to any folder. That in turns means you can't use hard-coded paths. Please enlighten me, how do you use absolute paths to make things safer for the lazy programmer. Because I'd say the lazy programmer is the one using hard-coded paths.

Comment: It seems that my perspective is far more different from a server admin one's.. And I think due to the fact that he accepted your answer as correct renders this discussion obsolete :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is an application with a form, I think it will only run if there is a user logged into the server. On server, most of the times there is no user logged in.

Applications that do stuff on the background or on a server should be coded as services.

Comment: Scheduled Tasks offers the option of logging in a user, and it does, all works fine.